# Tricky substring usage in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, case, text-extraction

I am looking for a way to retrieve always the 2 numbers after the last "/"character in a string. If there is something after the 2 numbers that I want, I don't care.

the code that I came up with is this:

```
CASE when INSTRUMENT like '%/%' then   SUBSTR(INSTRUMENT,INSTR(INSTRUMENT,'/',-3,1)+1,2) else '0' end
```

This seems to work fine.
The problem is that when it does not find any "/"character, then it does not fill them with a 0 as I would like.

To give you an example of what I would like to perform:

```
XXX/YYY/ZZZ/92           ---> Returns 92
XXX/YYY/ZZZ/42 (test)    ---> Returns 42
XXX YYY ZZZ 10           ---> Returns 0
```

All of this must be "plugged" in a select case statement, but this should not change the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get the point. If I run your query, the result I get is exactly the same than the needed result you posted; what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps regexp_substr will work for you.  If it returns NULL, meaning the pattern of a slash followed by 2 digits and 0 or more characters to the end of the string was not found, replace with a '0' by using NVL().

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select 'XXX/YYY/ZZZ/92' from dual union
      select 'XXX/YYY/ZZZ/42 (test)' from dual union
      select 'XXX YYY ZZZ 10' from dual
    )
    select nvl(regexp_substr(str, '/(\d{2}).*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '0') digits
    from tbl;

DIGITS
---------------------
0
42
92

SQL>
```